# Applying simple shear to two plates

Tags: stresses, shear

I read that the application of shear requires that equal and opposite forces are applied to two parallel plates. Why is this the case? If the force on one plate is transmitted through the material to the bottom surface, and the bottom surface is held so that it doesn't move by applying a force in the opposite direction from the force on the top plate, wouldn't that force also be experienced by the top plate, so that in both cases you aren't experiencing a net force? How do you hold the bottom plate so that it doesn't move?

Comment: bolt down the lower plate?  hold it in your hand?  I'm not getting what you don't understand here.

Answer (score 0):

The shear force is the force to break up/tear something into two pieces. It is most easily visualized by simple sketches.

Note that in the figures below, the shear force pairs are always acting/moving in opposite directions with identical magnitude.

[image]

Comment: Then how can you consider the lower plate to be held so that it doesn't move as I have seen explained?

Comment: See Tiger Guy's comment.